# Setting a single server credentials in Maven for multiple repositories (install)

Tags: maven

I've seen a lots of posts around **Maven and multiple repositories with single server credentials** like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511469/setting-a-single-server-credentials-in-maven-for-multiple-repositories).

However the general given solution is always for deploying artifact with the `distributionManagement` tag, which is not the needed answer. (we need to install deps -> `repositories` tag is needed)

Is there any other solution than having two duplicated `server` entries with same credentials but different ids?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using two credential entries, the other solution is to set the first repository in the **parent pom** of your project (or creating one) and the second repository in the **child pom**

-> you will be able to use the same ID for your repository without having the duplicate error.